# Cannot connect to EC2 using python boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I'm a complete noob with Python and boto and trying to establish a basic connection to ec2 services.
I'm running the following code:

```
ec2Conn = boto.connect_ec2('username','password')
group_name = 'python_central'
description = 'Python Central: Test Security Group.'
group = ec2Conn.create_security_group(group_name, description)
group.authorize('tcp', 8888,8888, '<a href="http://0.0.0.0/0">0.0.0.0/0</a>')
```

and getting the following error:
**AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials**

I've read some posts that this might be due to time difference between my machine and the EC2 server but according to the logs, they are the same:

> host:ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com x-amz-date:20161213T192005Z
>
> host;x-amz-date
>   515db222f793e7f96aa93818abf3891c7fd858f6b1b9596f20551dcddd5ca1be
>   2016-12-13 19:20:05,132 boto [DEBUG]:StringToSign:

Any idea how to get this connection running?

Thanks!

Comment: You use `boto` to launch instances, not connect to instances. Do you want to `ssh` into the instance you created?

Comment: Where are you getting `username` and `password` from? The AWS API doesn't take a username/password, it takes an access key and secret key. You appear to be confusing AWS API access and EC2 SSH access.

Comment: @helloV I do try to launch instances. Sample code taken from here:http://pythoncentral.io/introduction-to-python-on-aws-with-boto/

Comment: @MarkB You're correct, should be 'access key' and 'secret key'. Just looking to launch/shut down instances, no SSH connection involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call made to the AWS API require authentication via **Access Key** and **Secret Key**. These can be obtained from the Identity and Access Management (IAM) console, under the **Security Credentials** tab for a user.

See: [Getting Your Access Key ID and Secret Access Key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSGettingStartedGuide/AWSCredentials.html)

If you are unfamiliar with Python, you might find it easier to call AWS services by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). For example, this single-line command can launch an Amazon EC2 instance:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-c2d687ad --key-name joe --security-group-id sg-23cb34f6 --instance-type t1.micro
```

See: [AWS CLI `run-instances` documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html)